# javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException when I ask for a List<T> using JPA and Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, entitymanager, datastore

im having javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException when i want to, after retrieve all of my Entites as a List in my DAO implementation, ask for one atrribute object from my Entity.

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    this.entityManager = SingletonEntityManagerFactory.get().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = this.entityManager.getTransaction();
    try {
      tx.begin();
    return this.entityManager.createQuery(
        "select f from " + clazz.getName() + " as f").getResultList();

    }finally {
      tx.commit();
      if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
      }
      this.entityManager.close();
    }

  }
```

for instance, supposing T has a property of class A that is already an Entity persisted, i can't get A after having List

But i don't have this problem if I only look for a single Entity by Id. I obtain my entity and I can ask without problems for its attribute objects already persisted

```
public T getById(final Key id) {
   return getEntityManager().find(clazz, id);
}
```

now i can do

```
A a= t.getA();
```

How can I write my implementation of findAll() avoiding this error? maybe another Component instead of EntityManager? How can i make it generic, and not having to implement specific code for specific type of entities?

Answer (score 0):

What you do there doesn't make sure the field is loaded before leaving that method, so either access it, or make sure it is fetched by default.